# Google Analytics v1 SDK with Mobile Profile

Tags: ios, google-analytics

Google Analytics has been working just fine for my ios app (with GA v1.0), but I created a new profile in the analytics suite and set the profile type as "App". Now it's not working..

I have a sneaking suspicion that the "App" selection only works with GA v2.0? Can someone confirm?

BTW you can get create a new profile by opening a suite, click "Admin" (top right), then clicking "+ New Profile" (middle of page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that when you make a new profile for an ID you select a new

**1) Website**

or

**2) App**

What I didn't know was that SDK v1 works with a *Website* profile and SDK v2 works with an *App* profile. So if your app **WAS** tracking with google analytics and is no longer tracking then make sure you're using website tracking with SDK v1 and app tracking with SDK v2.

*Extra tip, after your profile has been active for +-12 hours you can check your app against the *real time* tracking. If real time tracking works, then you know you've set everything up correctly.